Ocelot - Dynamic Aggregate configuration on runtime
I am using Ocelot together with Consul to perform dynamic routing. Which works great. In addition, I am configuring aggregates, like:
{
  "Aggregates": [
    {
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/modules/dashboard/options",
      "RouteKeys": [
        "ServiceADashboardOptions",
        "ServiceBDashboardOptions"
      ],
      "Aggregator": "ArrayAggregator"
    }
}

Which works great. However, I would like to dynamically define the routes to be used for the aggregation based on tags a service has, when it is used in Consul.
In the example above, a service with the tag "dashboard" should be automatically considered for the aggregation. I don't know which services exists and how they are named at the point of configuration, but if they implement a feature the route pattern is defined.
I could see the following possibilities to achieve this behaviour:

Extending the service registration to use the Ocelot Gateway Administration API to update the configuration during service registration
Hooking the logic into a custom Middleware into the Ocelot request pipeline
Introducing a controller manually to the Ocelot project and do the aggregation "manually" after querying the service registry
Trying to provide a custom implementation of IServiceDiscovery and overwrite the PollConsul implementation with the addition of the Aggregate configuration
Adding a background worker service querying the Service registry and updating the aggregate files on disk
...

Are there any recommendations on which of the approaches would be conceptually correct. In short, what I would like to achieve is to create a dynamic aggregate route combining multiple service without knowing upfront which services exists or how they are names.
